# Java HTMLUnit Login not working?

Tags: java, screen-scraping, htmlunit

I have the following code to my website that I want to login to as shown below. There are no error messages when I run it, yet the HTML it returns at the end is of the original login page, suggesting that I have not logged in. I have tried it with multiple websites and the same thing keeps happening, so I am not sure whether it is not logging me in when I want it to, or whether it has something to do with cookies not being remembered when I go to the other page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlOption;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSelect;



public class testing {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

 java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF); 

final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("www.websiteneededtologinto.com");
HtmlElement usrname = page.getElementByName("Email");
usrname.click();
usrname.type("MYUSERNAME");
HtmlElement psswrd = page.getElementByName("Passwd");
psswrd.click();
psswrd.type("MYPASSWORD");
HtmlElement signin = page.getElementByName("signIn");
signin.click();



String html = Jsoup.connect("pagerequiringlogintoaccess.com").get().html();


System.out.println(html);
  }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue before, and to fix it I created methods to run all the functions:setText, getEid, and click. They are:

```
 public void click(HtmlElement el) throws Exception{
    page = el.click();
  }

  public void setText(HtmlElement el, String text){
    HtmlTextInput input = (HtmlTextInput)el;
    input.setText(text);
  }

 public HtmlElement getEid(String id){
    HtmlElement rval = null;
    boolean looking = true;
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < elementRetryCount && looking){
      try{
        rval = page.getHtmlElementById(id);
        looking = false;
      } catch (Exception e){
        try {
          Thread.sleep(elementRetryTimer * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      counter ++;
    }
    return rval;
  }
```

To run them the code would be something like:

```
scraper.setText(scraper.getEid("txtFromDate"), startingDate);
scraper.click(scraper.getEid("btnSubmit"));
```

Hope these changes help